# Why is Office add-in command slower than taskpane add-in?

Tags: excel, ms-office, office-js, office-addins

For some reason, office add-in command executes a bit slower than taskpane add-in in Excel Desktop.
Taskpane add-in executes almost instantly while add-in command takes a bit longer to execute. When executing add-in command  I can see a message in Excel status bar below which says office add-in is working on my add-in command which is not the case for taskpane add-in which just executes instantly without showing any messages in the status bar.

What could be the reason? I am in dev mode using npm start which opens a dev server(webpack)

(The performance is almost the same when in Excel on web)

(I am developing an add-in to automate formatting for a selected range for my company. I am wondering if I should switch to taskpane add-in rather than add-in command. But I want to use add-in command because our users perfer add-in command to taskpane add-in)

I am just using the samaple code in the link below. It is a simple code that changes the fill color of a given range

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/excel-quickstart-jquery?tabs=yeomangenerator

Add-in command version

```
async function setYellow(event) {
  try {
    await Excel.run(async (context) => {
      /**
       * Insert your Excel code here
       */
      const range = context.workbook.getSelectedRange();

      // Read the range address
      range.load("address");

      // Update the fill color
      range.format.fill.color = "yellow";

      await context.sync();
      event.completed();
    });
  } catch (error) {}
}
```

Taskpane version

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. Licensed under the MIT license.
 * See LICENSE in the project root for license information.
 */

/* global console, document, Excel, Office */

Office.onReady((info) => {
  if (info.host === Office.HostType.Excel) {
    document.getElementById("sideload-msg").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("app-body").style.display = "flex";
    document.getElementById("run").onclick = run;
  }
});

export async function run() {
  try {
    await Excel.run(async (context) => {
      /**
       * Insert your Excel code here
       */
      const range = context.workbook.getSelectedRange();

      // Read the range address
      range.load("address");

      // Update the fill color
      range.format.fill.color = "yellow";

      await context.sync();
      console.log(`The range address was ${range.address}.`);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the user clicks an add-in command, an entirely new embedded JavaScript runtime is launched. The code in the command runs and when the `event.completed()` runs, the runtime is shut down. The next time the command is executed, the whole process is repeated.

With a task pane, the runtime starts up when the task pane is opened. So when you press the button on the task pane, it can immediately run the code. It doesn't have to spin up a new runtime.

There's some background information in [Runtimes in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/testing/runtimes).